# DCNM Lincense Allocation

Tags: cisco, cisco-nexus-5k, nms, nx-os

I recently installed Cisco DCNM (Data Center Network Manager) and my trial license has expired but I would like to continue to use the free Essentials license for my 5K switches.  Can anyone advise what I need to do to apply the license?  Is it just a matter of taking the .lic files from each switch and assigning them to the switch in the DCNM UI?

Any advice is appreciated

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Download the license pack file that you received from Cisco <***L-DCNM-L-N5K-K9=***> into a directory on the server system.

> Copy the license file into INSTALL_DIR/dcnm/licenses directory. On a
>   Microsoft Windows system, the default INSTALL_DIR value is C:\Program
>   Files\Ciscoystems.Add License File.

2. You can view the existing Cisco DCNM licenses.

> Start the License Wizard by choosing Admin > License

3. Adding Cisco DCNM Licenses

> Step 1 Start the License Wizard by choosing Admin > License.
>   Step 2 Click on the Server License File tab.
>   Step 3 Click Add License File.

4. Assigning Licenses

> Step 1 Start the License Wizard by choosing Admin > License.
>   Step 2 From the table, select the switch that you want to assign the license to
>   Step 3 Click Assign License.

also you can make use of this link [Installing and Managing Licenses for Cisco Data Center Network Manager](http://www.cisco.com/c/en/us/td/docs/switches/datacenter/sw/6_x/dcnm/installation/published/install/licensing_DCNM.html#35007)